# Inheritance About Mixin and Class Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Please look the code ,i want to know 
1.who is C super
2.in the class C ,when i call 'super.method()', Mixin excute 'void method()'(so C's super is Mixin?), then, when excute 'super.method()', B excute 'void method()'(so C's super is B?),why?

It's running Dart 2.1.2

```
void main() {
  C().printSuper();
  C().method();
}

abstract class A {
  void method() {
    print("A");
  }
}

class B implements A {
  @override
  void method() {
    print("B");
  }
}

mixin Mixin on A {
  @override
  void method() {
    super.method();
    print("mixin");
  }
}

class C extends B with Mixin {
  void printSuper() {
    super.method();
  }
}



print message:

I/flutter (21340): B
I/flutter (21340): mixin
I/flutter (21340): B
I/flutter (21340): mixin
```

i expected the output print message:

I/flutter (21340): B
I/flutter (21340): B
I/flutter (21340): mixin

Answer (score 1):

The superclass of `C` is `B with Mixin`, which is an anonymous class introduced by the `extends B with Mixin` clause.

The class `C` is equivalent to a class declared as follows:

```
class _BwithMixin extends B implements Mixin {
  void method() {
    super.method();
    print("mixin");
  }
}
class C extends _BwithMixin {
  void printSuper() {
    super.method();
  }
}
```

So, the `printSuper` doesn't directly hit the `method` of `B`, it hits the `method` of the superclass of `C` which is `B with Mixin`, and that method is the one copied from `Mixin`. It will then call `super.method()` from `_BwithMixin`, and the superclass of that is `B`, so it will first print `mixin` and then `B`.

Comment: Thank you! I've leaned.But, i still a little confused.  mixin Mixin on A {
  @override
  void method() {
    super.method();
    print("mixin");
  }
}   ,when performing the super.method, why class 'B' perfoming method?

Comment: In the equivalent classes that I wrote, the `Mixin.method` copied into `B with Mixin` will call `super.method()`. The `super` of `B with Mixin` is `B`, so `B with Mixin`'s `method` will call `B`'s `method` in its `super.method()` invocation. I have updated the original answer with this as well.

Comment: I undersdand.Thank you very much!

Comment: but why _BwithMixin carries method() from Mixin and not from B.Pl update